# Custom types in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, custom-type

How to create custom type in Angular. can anyone please show it how to implement it at the component level?
I know about the below part

```
type Programmer = {
  name: string;
  knownFor: string[];
};
const ada: Programmer = {
  name: 'Ada Lovelace',
  knownFor: ['Mathematics', 'Computing', 'First Programmer']
};
```

But how to actually create it and use it in the Angular component?
Thanks.

Comment: Like this. `export interface Programmer {
  name: string;
  knownFor: string[];
}`

Answer (score 2):

Create custom `type` using `interface`. file name `Programmer.ts`.

**Programmer.ts**

```
export interface Programmer {
  name: string;
  knownFor: string[];
}
```

**MyComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Programmer } from './programmer'; // import the custom type

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {
  ada: Programmer = {
    name: 'Ada Lovelace',
    knownFor: ['Mathematics', 'Computing', 'First Programmer']
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h2>{{ ada.name }}</h2>
  <p>Known for:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of ada.knownFor">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```